# Why won't osx 10.5.8 connect to WPA2

Tags: macos, wpa2

I have a PowerBook G4 with a standard AirPort card (not AirPort Extreme) and I'm trying to connect it to a WPA2 secured network (WRT54G) other computers and iPhones connect to it fine (i've got about 4 laptops and 2 iPhones running on it at various times) but when I select the network on this power book it keeps telling me it can't connect.

When I select it the network asks for a WPA password and WPA2 does not appear as a selectable option. Is this a problem with AirPort/AirPort Extreme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non extreme airport cards don't support WPA2.  Use WPA only.

Comment: If that's true it sucks a lot. Do you have any documentation to back that up?