# Powerbook G4 with Airport Extreme card and Leopard won't connect with WPA2

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, g4

Like the author of [Why won't osx 10.5.8 connect to WPA2](https://superuser.com/questions/162543/why-wont-osx-10-5-8-connect-to-wpa2) I have a Powerbook G4 I would like to connect to Wifi, but when I try it will only ask for WPA. Unlike them my Powerbook has an Airport Extreme card, which was supposed to be the requirement for WPA2.

Comment: Do you have a retro AP to go with that retro Mac? It would be interesting to know if it can connect to the first AirPort Extreme base station (the 802.11g one). Wi-Fi beacons and other behaviors have gotten much more complicated in the decade+ since then. Maybe modern APs are do things that confuse that ancient software.

Comment: No, but maybe I should just for completeness. It's not a cherry Powerbook, I replaced the original drive with an SSD (yes, PATA SSDs are a thing).

Leopard should be compatible with WPA2, though. It had been out for three years when Leopard was released.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use wireless but I do manage the old Netgear family router which for many years has been set to 'WPA-PSK + WPA2-PSK'. This has served us well from G3s to the latest iPad and laptops. The router's short description is:

'WPA-PSK + WPA2-PSK - Allow clients using either WPA-PSK or WPA2-PSK. Encryption types TKIP or AES are supported, but both WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK must use the same encryption type.'

From memory you may get slightly different options depending upon how you first use wireless. I think the preference panel and wireless symbol at the top of the screen differ.